# Are there methods for finding not optimal but good linear approximations for functions?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, linear-cryptanalysis

I'm interested in finding the best, or maybe just a good linear approximation of the function $F^{(19)}: V_{56}\to V_8$, where 
$$
\begin{array}{l}
F^{(1)}(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_7) = P(x_2+x_6);  \\  F^{(2)}(x_1,\ldots,x_7) =
F^{(1)}(x_2,\ldots,x_7,F^{(1)}(x_1,\ldots,x_7)), 
\\ F^{(3)}(x_1,\ldots,x_7) = F^{(1)}\left(x_3,\ldots,x_7, F^{(1)}(x_1,\ldots,x_7), F^{(2)}(x_1,\ldots, x_7) \right) \ldots
\end{array} 
$$
Here $x_j\in V_8$, $P$ is a byte permutation and by $+$ we denote addition in $V_8$.

Are there methods for finding not optimal but good linear approximations for such a function?

Comment: I am having some difficult determining exactly what your function is/how your function works. It looks like it maps a 56 bit input to an 8 bit output?

Comment: Ella Rose, you are right. The best linear approximation means finding $l' \in V_{56}, l'' \in V_8$ such that $P \{l'x + l''F^{(19)}(x) = 0\}$ is high